# Nginx Problem with Joomla Backend (Cloudflare Error 520)

Tags: nginx, server

**Hey everyone!**

I'm having a really hard time figuring this out, when i run my website with apache, everything works as intended, however i recently switched to nginx, when i run my website on nginx and access the joomla backend  i get an Error 520 from Cloudflare, i can't find out the difference in the two webservers, but it seems related to SSL, running without SSL works fine.
I'm out of luck i did a lot of testing and still the same issue.
Something that Cloudflare cannot understand is happening when using Nginx.

This is my Nginx Config

```
 server {
        
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen 80;
        
        server_name websitename.com www.websitename.com;
        
        root  /var/www/html;
    
        ssl_certificate websitename.com.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key websitename.com.key;
        
            index index.php index.html index.htm default.html default.htm;

             location / {
                    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
            }
    

            location ~* /(images|cache|media|logs|tmp)/.*\.(php|pl|py|jsp|asp|sh|cgi)$ {
                    return 403;
                    error_page 403 /403_error.html;
            }
    
            location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
            }
    

            location ~* \.(ico|pdf|flv)$ {
                    expires 1y;
            }
    
            location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|swf|xml|txt)$ {
                    expires 14d;
            }
            
    }
```

Comment: I even tried this stuff  client_header_buffer_size 64k;
 large_client_header_buffers 4 64k;
 http2_max_field_size 64k; PLZ SEND HELP

Comment: If you are a Joomla user or developer, please join [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

**Finally i solved it.**

Finally i found out that somehow the Cloudflare Railgun isn't behaving right with Nginx

I went to Cloudflare and navigated to "Speed->Optimizations" I disabled the Railgun
and i no longer have 520 Errors.

Hope this helps anyone with the same issue, been 3 days stuck on this.